# The target server failed to respond for multiple iterations in Jmeter

Tags: server, jmeter, target

In my Jmeter script,I am getting error for 2nd iteration.
For multiple users with single iteration, no errors were observed, but with multiple iterations am getting error with below message

**Response code**: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException
**Response message**: Non HTTP response message: The target server failed to respond

Response data is **The target server failed to respond**

[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIqEH.png)

Could you please suggest me what could be reason behind this error

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your server becomes overloaded. In regards to possible reason my expectation is that single iteration does not deliver the full concurrency as JMeter acts like:

- JMeter starts all the virtual users within the specified ramp-up period
- Each virtual user starts executing samplers
- When there are no more samplers to execute and no loops to iterate - the thread is being shut down

So with 1 iteration you may run into situation when some threads have already finished their job and the others have not been started yet. When you add more iterations the "old" threads start over and "new" are arriving. The situation is explained in the [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) article and you can monitor the actual delivered load using **Active Threads Over Time** chart of the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) or [Active Threads Over Time Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)

To get to the bottom of the failure I would recommend checking the following:

- components logs on the application under test side (application logs, application/web server logs, database logs)
- application under test baseline health metrics (CPU, RAM, Disk, etc.). You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/), this way you will be able to correlate increasing load with resources consumption

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri , but my case is 1 user 1 iteration is working fine

Comment: but my case is 1 user 1 iteration is working fine, 1 user 2 iterations is also getting failed with same error

Comment: Inspect requests which are being sent for 1st and 2nd iteration using [View Results Tree Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree), it might be the case of incorrectly working parametrization or something like that. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article to get familiarized wit htroubleshooting techniques

Comment: I have fixed the issue.. By default implementation type is not selected anything, I tried giving implementation type as "JAVA". It started working for all iterations and all users

Comment: May I know the Significance of Implementation type in HTTP Sampler